# Valid containers (mp4, mov, avi, mkv, web) for codecs in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-codecs

Typically I use the following codecs - h.264, h.265, vp9, dnxhd, cineform and prores. I consider the following to be valid containers for these codecs.

```
Codec     MP4.  MOV.  AVI.  MKV.  WEBM.   
H.264     Yes.  Yes.  Yes.  Yes.  No.
H.265     Yes.  Yes.  Yes.  Yes.  No.
VP9       Yes.  No.   No.   No.   Yes.
DNxHD     No.   Yes.  Yes.  No.   No. 
CFHD      No.   Yes.  Yes.  No.   No. 
ProRes    No.   Yes.  Yes.  No.   No.
```

I understand the -pix_fmts option. However, I am still unable to figure out all the valid combinations of codecs+containers

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47276731/).

Comment: The downvote is unfair. I looked at other solutions and the grep using codec id does not offer the complete  info. There is a stub c code provided except I was interested in the ffmpeg cli. Not libavcodec.

Answer (score 1):

The best source of information might be Wikipedia
[Comparison of video container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats).

Although it was last updated on November 2013, it's still
relatively complete.
(For H.264 and H.265 see below comment by Mokubai.)

I note that the data in the article is not always identical to yours.
For example, VP9 is listed as compatible with MKV.

Comment: h.264 *is* in that list, it is just named as "MPEG-4 AVC" as is h.265 where it is named "MPEG-H HEVC".  A note under the table states "HEVC is not mentioned in the latest draft of Matroska, but MKVToolNix and VLC support it."

Comment: @Mokubai: Thanks - corrected.

Comment: The link is completely outdated. No info on mov container. Or about dnxhd, cineform or prores.

Comment: @moi `mov` is listed as `QTFF` because it is the "QuickTime File Format". Wikipedia is freely editable, so if you can enhance the list with what you have found then they'd probably appreciate it.